# manyind index unwanted space before comma

Tags: spacing, makeindex, manyind

I get an unwanted space after every index keyword when using the [manyind](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/manyind) package.

I don't understand what am I doing wrong since when I try to compile the `manyind` [documentation](https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~kalle101/mindsample.tex), the index turns out fine.

MWE (replace `manyind` by `makeidx` to see propper behaviour):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{manyind}
%\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\index{abc}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

See the extra space after the term *abc*, before comma below.

[image: current behaviour]

Comment: I can confirm this -- the white space is within `\indexentry` of the `.idx` file.

Comment: In my opinion, you should use `imakeidx` rather than this weird package (sorry!)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am using `manyind` to separate terms into multiple indices. Is this possible using `imakeidx`too?

Comment: Yes, that's why I mentioned that package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in `manyind.sty`, basically right at the start within `\AtBeginDocument{...}`:

```
 \protected@write
    \@indexfile {}{\string \indexentry
    {\ind@nr#1 }{\thepage}}%
  \endgroup
```

must be changed to

```
\protected@write
   \@indexfile {}{\string \indexentry
  {\ind@nr #1}{\thepage}}%
  \endgroup
```

i.e. the space between `\ind@nr` and `#1` does matter here.

Following code fixes this.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{manyind}

\makeatletter

\AtBeginDocument{\def\ind@nr#1{\string\indnr\mindchoice d\gr@bltr#1-\relax b #1}%
\ifx\@@wrindex\undefined
\def\@wrindex#1{\@bsphack 
\protected@write
    \@indexfile {}{\string \indexentry
    {\ind@nr #1}{\thepage}}%
  \endgroup
\@esphack}%
\else
\def\@wrindex#1{\@@wrindex\ind@nr#1||\\}%
\fi
\setindex{main}}%

\makeatother
%\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex



\begin{document}
\blindtext[1]\index{abc} \index{cdef}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Ondrian: The  package author(s) should informed about the bug

Comment: Yes, I informed him right after I saw your answer.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me maintain my weird package.